# UDP C Sockets: Multiple Sockets Sharing Single Port

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, gnu

I'm writing a program in C on GNU/Linux that uses UDP to communicate messages between various instances of the program, either on a single machine, or across a network. Each instance of the program has it's own unique internal application layer address that it uses to differentiate between instances that run on a single machine (and thus share an IP address). Currently, the whole system communicates on a single UDP port.

This works fine between instances of the program running on separate machines, as these all have unique IP addresses, and thus unique socket connections. The problem is running multiple instances on a single machine. In this case, only the first instance of the program gets a socket connect and the others fail since the port is already in use.

Is there a way to bind multiple datagram sockets to a single port? I realize this is not normally advisable, but since I have unique application layer addresses that I can use to resolve the ambiguity, it would be helpful in this case. Essentially, I want to be able to do the following:

1. Bind all instances of the program on a single machine to the same common protocol port
2. When a message is received, each instance will use recv with the MSG_PEEK flag set to determine if the message's application layer address matches the instance's internal address.
3. For the single instance on a given machine where the addresses match, a regular call to recv will remove the message from the input queue for processing by the appropriate instance.

Essentially, I wish to use UDP as a common communication medium with more specific addressing occurring at the application layer.

Is there a standard way of doing this in GNU C? I realize that I could write a top level governing program to listen to all messages on the socket and reroute them to the appropriate instance, but this seems unnecessarily complicated, and breaks the program operating identically with multiple instances across a network vs across a shared single IP. I also know I could use multiple ports, but this adds the need to assign each instance a separate free port and keep track of these across the entire network of instances.

Essentially, I wish to "Broadcast" a message to a group of instances sharing a single IP address and let them sort out who the message belongs to at the application layer.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can do such binding with setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT), but I think it would not help. You will have several sockets, each with its own packet queue, and each packet will go in one queue only. MSG_PEEK will do no good.

Top-level instance rerouting messages to different consumers looks like right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the multiple socket bound to a unique ip/port combination.

Use some message queue / message passing interface, and forget about UDP.
For example, see 0MQ (zeromq) http://www.zeromq.org/

Answer (score 0):

If it's a client/server style app, the client side need not bind.

When the server responds to the client that hasn't bound it will respond to the source port which will be randomly chosen by the OS when the client sends (without bind).
The client then reads from the unbound port.